# Redis Modules API - Implementing LRANGE

Tags: redis

I'm trying to use the modules API to quickly retrieve all of the values stored in list for aggregation (~10M values). LPUSH and LPOP have been implemented in the low level API, but there's no equivalent for LRANGE.

I'm able to call LRANGE with the high level API, but the performance is only slightly better than RcppRedis/hiredis.  I can also use ListPop and ListPush to recreate LRANGE by storing the RedisModuleString output from ListPop, but this is also understandably slow.

High-level API with RedisModule_Call:

```c
int LRange(RedisModuleCtx *ctx, RedisModuleString **argv, int argc) {
  if (argc < 2) return RedisModule_WrongArity(ctx);
  RedisModule_AutoMemory(ctx);

  RedisModuleCallReply *highAPI;
  highAPI = RedisModule_Call(ctx, "LRANGE", "scc", argv[1], "0", "-1");
...
```

Low-level API with ListPop and ListPush:

```c
int LRange(RedisModuleCtx *ctx, RedisModuleString **argv, int argc) {
  if (argc < 2) return RedisModule_WrongArity(ctx);
  RedisModule_AutoMemory(ctx);

  RedisModuleKey *key;
  key = RedisModule_OpenKey(ctx,argv[1],REDISMODULE_READ|REDISMODULE_WRITE);

  size_t *len;
  len = RedisModule_ValueLength(key);

  for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    RedisModuleString *ele;
    ele = RedisModule_ListPop(key,REDISMODULE_LIST_HEAD);
    RedisModule_ListPush(key,REDISMODULE_LIST_TAIL,ele);

  }

  return RedisModule_ReplyWithSimpleString(ctx, "OK");
}
```

RedisModule_Call returns in about 1.3 seconds and ListPop -> ListPish returns in about 3.9 seconds for ~10M values.

Is there another way to use the low-level Redis Modules API to pull values from a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently (v5.0.5) there is no API for iterating or fetching ranges of lists.